# How to replace filter and .distinct() with another filter and .first() when subquery returns no result in Django Python?

Tags: python, django

I've got a subquery who returning some data depending of a specific filter. This specific filter sometime return null result but what I want is to catch the first() result without specific filter if no result return with.

```
date_filter = Q(start_date__lte=OuterRef('object_start_date'), end_date__gte=OuterRef('object_start_date')) | \
    Q(start_date__lte=OuterRef('object_start_date'), end_date=None)
```

The query where i use this filter

```
data_subquery = Object.objects.filter(date_filter).filter(user=OuterRef('user')).distinct()
```

This subquery is used here next :

```
main_subquery = Main.annotate(role=Subquery(data_subquery.values('role__name')[:1]))
```

I've to anonymized data but the goal is to understand the need ....

The filter subquery ***datefilter** *should be used if ***data_subquery*** return something ... else I don't need this filter and want to replace ***.disctinct()*** by ***.first()***

THanks for your help :)

I've got a function to return specific data depending on user and date given in parameters ... or first one ... but I don't know how to use function into subquery ;)

I tried to add :

```
if len(data_subquery) == 0:    
    data_subquery = Object.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user')).filter()
```

But it can't work with subquery :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subqueries` are evaluated in the database, not in Python code, this is why you have a problem.

You can achieve the result you want by using Django's `Coalesce` database function in conjunction with the `Subquery` function.

We create two subqueries: the first one with the filter and the second one without the filter. Then, use `Coalesce` to return the first non-null result from the two `subqueries`

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

date_filter = Q(start_date__lte=OuterRef('object_start_date'), end_date__gte=OuterRef('object_start_date')) | \
    Q(start_date__lte=OuterRef('object_start_date'), end_date=None)

data_subquery_with_filter = Object.objects.filter(
    date_filter,
    user=OuterRef('user')
).values('role__name')[:1]

data_subquery_without_filter = Object.objects.filter(
    user=OuterRef('user')
).values('role__name')[:1]

main_subquery = Main.objects.annotate(
    role=Coalesce(
        Subquery(data_subquery_with_filter),
        Subquery(data_subquery_without_filter)
    )
)
```